# Search tags with nested boolean operators?

Tags: support, search

I have a search query to find easy-peasy questions to answer, but no ways that I've tried have worked.

---

```
[syntax-error] AND ( [javascript] OR [python] ) is:question closed:no duplicate:no locked:no answers:0
```

[image]

---

```
[syntax-error] AND [javascript] OR [syntax-error] AND [python] is:question closed:no duplicate:no locked:no answers:0
```

[image]

---

```
[syntax-error][javascript] OR [syntax-error][python] is:question closed:no duplicate:no locked:no answers:0
```

[image]

---

The boolean operators for tags aren't working. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: The second and third should work, by what I know.

Comment: ... Easy questions tend to be already-answered, unles you do [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). Bad strategy. Also, most of those should be closed as typo.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### There is no "AND" operator

The issues here is that you're using the non-existent operator "AND"; neither can you use brackets to group search terms.

Simply exclude this word and you'll get some results:

[`[syntax-error] [javascript] OR [python] is:q closed:no duplicate:no locked:no answers:..0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bsyntax-error%5D%20%5Bjavascript%5D%20OR%20%5Bpython%5D%20is%3Aq%20closed%3Ano%20duplicate%3Ano%20locked%3Ano%20answers%3A..0&mixed=0)

---

#### Advanced Search UI

If you need some help building advanced search queries, I recommend using my [Advanced Search Helper, Saved Search (Bookmarks), and Navigation Improvements](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011) userscript.

[image]

**Features:**

1. Search main/meta switcher
2. Switch to main/meta from left sidebar
3. Order-by selector
4. Username & Tag autocomplete
5. **Saved searches**!!!

   - Toggle from search results page

     [image: screenshot]
   - View list via toggle button in Advanced Search Helper

     [image: screenshot]

Comment: I've never had this issue before, but now that it comes up, the fact that SO search has an "OR" operator but not an "AND" operator surprises me (from a UI perspective), especially for a programming-focused website. Is there a NOT operator so an enterprising young whippersnapper can re-implement AND logic via NORs? :)

Comment: @tonysdg You cannot combine `-` & `or` together. Perhaps you would like to make a [[feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=feature-request)]?

Comment: Nah, as you've pointed out, "AND" operations more or less work (if not quite symmetrically to OR ops). No point in muddying the waters (for now).